# Plot multi graphs in one window

Tags: plotting, graphics, plot-themes

I want to plot a graph of a function in one command

```
y=Sin[a+bx+c]+d;
```

for the range of `x=[0,10]` for the below set of values

1.`a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1`

2.`a=1.5,b=1.5,c=1.5,d=1.5`

3.`a=2,b=2,c=2,d=2`

Answer (score 2):

```
rules = Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> #] & /@ {1, 1.5, 2};
Plot[Evaluate[Sin[a + b x + c] + d /. rules], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> ToString /@ rules]
```

[image]

```
rule4 = Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> {1, 2, 4, 3}]
```

> {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 3}

```
rulesb =  Append[rules, rule4];

Plot[Evaluate[Sin[a + b x + c] + d /. rulesb], {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> ToString /@ rulesb]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's great. if values of variables are different from each other then how can plot. like `a=1,b=1.2,c=1.4,d=1.6` `a=2,b=2.2,c=2.4,d=2.6` `a=3,b=3.2,c=3.4,d=3.6`

Comment: @Mathematicain, please see the update.